# mayavi displays volume slices wrong

Tags: python, visualization, backend, display, mayavi

I tried the following python code to display multiple volume slices with mayavi:

```
import numpy as np
import mayavi.mlab as mlab

# creating volume that increases in value
img3d = np.arange(20)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=1)
img3d = np.expand_dims(img3d, axis=2)
img3d = np.tile(img3d, (1, 20, 20))

fig = mlab.figure()
src = mlab.pipeline.scalar_field(img3d)

# Plotting two cut planes
cp2 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(src, plane_orientation='y_axes')
cp2.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False
cp3 = mlab.pipeline.scalar_cut_plane(src, plane_orientation='z_axes')
cp3.implicit_plane.widget.enabled = False
mlab.view(azimuth=50, elevation=None)
mlab.outline()
mlab.show()
```

and received the following display:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNcD8.png)

the displayed order is wrong. What could be the cause and how do I fix this problem?.
I am using python 3.7.6. on a Ubuntu 18.04.4.

Comment: Your code works perfectly on my machine. What do you get when you run `mayavi2` and click on About in the Help tab?

Comment: The console command gives me: 

Authors: Prabhu Ramachandran
and Gael Varoquaux
Mayavi version 4.5.0 - VTK version 6.3.0
Python 2.7.17 
wxPython 3.0.2.0
Copyright © 2003-2010 Enthought, Inc.

However, somehow python 2.7 is running in the background.
If I use the above code with python 3.7.6 there is no "About" option.

Comment: I have the following: Mayavi version 4.7.1 - VTK version 8.1.2; Python 3.6.9; Qt 5.14.2.1. Perhaps consider upgrading?